# AppLaud + jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 + jQuery 1.10.1 + Phonegap 1.9.0 (why not work?)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, applaud

friends,
I'm starting to develop in AppLaud applications with PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile.

Applaud started a new project:
- JQuery 1.7.2
- JQuery Mobile 1.3.1
- PhoneGap 1.9.0

My folder assets is as follows:

```
- [assets]
- [www]
--- [jquery.mobile]
---- [images]
---- jquery-1.7.2.min
---- jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css
---- jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js
---- jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css
---- jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js
--- cordova-1.9.0.js
--- index.html
```

and my index.html file contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Minimal AppLaud App</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var onDeviceReady = function() {
            document.getElementById("devready").innerHTML = "OnDeviceReady fired.";
        };

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }   
</script>  

  </head>
  <body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">
    <h2>Minimal AppLaud App</h2>

    <p>Your app goes here.</p>
    <p>
    <span id="devready">onDeviceReady not fired.</span>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following errors in the Eclipse IDE:

"Syntax error on token" Invalid Regular Expression Options', the accurate correction available "- jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js - line 2

"The default case is already defined" - jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js - line 2034

"The default case is already defined" - jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js - line 8700

What might be happening?
With these errors I can not even test the application.

Comment: Are you using jquery-1.7.2.min or jquery-1.10.1.min like you mentioned in a title?

Comment: @Gajotres, sorry, i'm using 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
Actually is some internal error Eclipse.
sufficed I disable **JavaScript Validator** in *Project> Properties> Builders*

If someone has been having this problem, here's the solution.