# Applaud How to change JQuery Mobile version

Tags: android, cordova, applaud

I am new to phone gap, i am creating new project by using Applaud plugin. But i am unable to get new version of jQuery in that. Please help me how to get latest version.
Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474148/applaud-jquery-mobile-1-3-1-jquery-1-10-1-phonegap-1-9-0-why-not-work

Comment: i Saw that URL, But that is not my case. I am not getting version 1.4.2 at the time of project creation